# CONCAT within SQL CASE Statement in Snowflake

Tags: sql, concatenation, case, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, string-length

I am trying to convert the data in a column REVENUE_MONTH for example to 03 instead of 3. I would also be concatenating that new column along with the existing REVENUE_MONTH and REVENUE_YEAR columns to get something like 2020-03-01 instead of 2020-3-01. Below are my two approaches,

1. Using IN

```
CONCAT(REVENUE_YEAR,'-',CAST(CASE WHEN REVENUE_MONTH IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9) THEN CONCAT(0,REVENUE_MONTH) ELSE REVENUE_MONTH END AS NUMBER(38,0)),'-','01')
```

2. USING LENGTH()

```
CONCAT(REVENUE_YEAR,'-',CAST(CASE WHEN LENGTH(REVENUE_MONTH)=1 THEN CONCAT(0,REVENUE_MONTH) ELSE REVENUE_MONTH END AS NUMBER(38,0)),'-','01')
```

Unfortunately both of them are returning 2020-3-01 instead of the expected 2020-03-01

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try LPAD? below should work

CONCAT(REVENUE_YEAR,'-', LPAD(REVENUE_MONTH,2,'0'),'-','01')

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT column1, RIGHT('0' || CAST(column1 AS varchar(2)), 2) as month
FROM VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12)
ORDER BY 1;
```

gives:

```
COLUMN1 MONTH
1   01
2   02
3   03
4   04
5   05
6   06
7   07
8   08
9   09
10  10
11  11
12  12
```

but it can also be:

```
SELECT column1, RIGHT('0' || column1::text, 2) as month
FROM VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12)
ORDER BY 1;
```

but what you really want is [LPAD](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/lpad.html)

```
SELECT column1, LPAD( column1, 2, '0') as month
FROM VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12)
ORDER BY 1;
```